# When I use the reduce method, it isn't totaling the array, it is more like joining the array together

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I want to total the array using the reduce method. I would use a for loop and keep it simple, but it is for my college course.

```
console.log(weeklyTotal);

const totalCal = weeklyTotal.reduce((total, current) => total + current, 0);

console.log(totalCal);
```

[Here is what shows in the Chrome dev tools console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4os2.png)

Comment: convert current to a number before adding it: `total + Number(current)`, otherwise, you'll be doing string concatenation rather than addition

Comment: @NickParsons Why do people comment their responses instead of replying normally? Also, I didn't realize that the array was all strings. Can I use parseInt instead, or is using Number the newer version? I'm not exactly familiar with Number although I have seen it before. Also, thanks.

Comment: I commented my answer because I felt like your question was going to get closed (which it did), as this is a small mistake which is either a duplicate or a typo-like question. `parseInt(current, 10)` will also work, `Number()` is generally preferred as it will work if you have both integer strings and decimal strings, so it's more versatile

Comment: @NickParsons While using parseInt(current, 10), what does the 10 do?

Comment: The `10` specifies the "radix" of your input string, here we specify 10, so the base10 number, if you had a base2 (aka binary) string and you wanted to convert it to an integer (eg: "101" is 5 in binary), you can use `parseInt("101", 2)`. 10 is technically not the default radix, so its usually good to supply